# Updating just a subset of fields in a row

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3

I'm learning asp.net MVC.  Using the Code First model, where you create your class, and then use the EF to manage all database interactions.

Is there anyway of only requesting some of the fields from a given table using this method, and only updating those fields?

My whole class is:

```
Public Class Employee
  Public Property ID() As Integer
  <DisplayName("Staff Name")>
  <Required()>
  Public Property StaffName() As String
  <DisplayName("Location")>
  <Required()>
  Public Property Location() As String
  <Required()>
  <DisplayName("Team Leader")>
  Public Property teamleader() As String

  Public Property ScoreCardM1() As Integer
  Public Property ScoreCardM1Notes() As String
  Public Property ScoreCardM2() As Integer
  Public Property ScoreCardM2Notes() As String
  Public Property ScoreCardM3() As Integer
  Public Property ScoreCardM3Notes() As String
  Public Property ScoreCardM4() As Integer
  Public Property ScoreCardM4Notes() As String
  Public Property ScoreCardM5() As Integer
  Public Property ScoreCardM5Notes() As String
  Public Property ScoreCardM6() As Integer
  Public Property ScoreCardM6Notes() As String
  Public Property ScoreCardTotal() As Integer
  Public Property ScoreCardTotalNotes() As String
  Public Property ScoreCardM7() As Integer
  Public Property ScoreCardM7Notes() As String
  Public Property ScoreCardM8() As Integer
  Public Property ScoreCardM8Notes() As String
  Public Property ScoreCardM9() As Integer
  Public Property ScoreCardM9Notes() As String
  Public Property ScoreCardQ3Total() As Integer
  Public Property ScoreCardQ3TotalNotes() As String
  Public Property ScoreCardM10() As Integer
  Public Property ScoreCardM10Notes() As String
  Public Property ScoreCardM11() As Integer
  Public Property ScoreCardM11Notes() As String
  Public Property ScoreCardM12() As Integer
  Public Property ScoreCardM12Notes() As String
  Public Property ScoreCardQ4Total() As Integer
  Public Property ScoreCardQ4TotalNotes() As String
  Public Property GeneralNotes() As String
End Class
```

However, I only want to display and edit one month at a time:

```
Public Class Employee
  Public Property ID() As Integer
  <DisplayName("Staff Name")>
  <Required()>
  Public Property StaffName() As String

  Public Property ScoreCardM1() As Integer
  Public Property ScoreCardM1Notes() As String
End Class
```

How do I best achieve this?  Do I setup another 12 classes, with just one month contained within each, or is there a best practice way of updating a subset of fields within a database row, without affecting the others?

Thanks for any help,

Mark

Comment: Hi - I may have found the answer here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6200901/updating-only-part-of-a-model - which I didn't see when searching.  If anyone has any other suggestions for best practice, please let me know - thanks again, Mark

Comment: The linked answer suggests requerying the database for the edited record, and updating it with the model passed into the controller.  This seems like you're doing an extra query (reselecting the record to be updated).  Is that really the best way of achieving this?  Thanks, Mark

Comment: You can always just create one Month class and add a new property for the name of the month. Then you can have collection of month report in your employee class.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

further to my comment above.... you can set up your classes as follow:

Employee Class:

```
Public Class Employee
  Public Property EmployeeID() As Integer
  <DisplayName("Staff Name")>
  <Required()>
  Public Property StaffName() As String
  <DisplayName("Location")>
  <Required()>
  Public Property Location() As String
  <Required()>
  <DisplayName("Team Leader")>
  Public Property teamleader() As String
  Public virtual Property reports() As ICollection<Of MonthlyRports> // not sure if the syntax is right (haven't worked in VB)
End Class
```

MonthlyReport Class

```
Public Class Employee
  Public Property MonthlyReportID() As Integer // primary key
  Public Property EmployeeID() As Integer // foreign key. who this report belongs to
  Public Property Month As String // report for month ...
  Public Property ScoreCard() As Integer
  Public Property ScoreCardNotes() As String
End Class
```